# How can I add code about token is expired in kotlin?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit2

> D/OkHttp: {"code":60200,"message":"Token is not valid"}

->Token is not valid. so I want to add content about the token is expired and then go to `mainactivity`.

```
  private fun startLoading() {

    val handler = Handler()
    handler.postDelayed(Runnable {
        val savedToken = SaveSharedPreference.getUserInfo(this)
        if (savedToken != null) {

            val intent = Intent(this, ManagementActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        if (savedToken != null) {
            Client.retrofitService.confirm(savedToken).enqueue(object :
                Callback<LoginResponse> {
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<LoginResponse>?,
                    response: Response<LoginResponse>?
                ) {
                    Log.d(_tag, "Token: $savedToken")
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {
                   failToConfirm()
                }
            })
        }


  },3000)
}
```

Comment: This is splashactvity code. I already make failToConfirm()                             private fun failToConfirm() {
  val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
  startActivity(intent)
  finish()
  }

Comment: Please edit your quesion if you want to add information instead of commenting it.